# Trying to get an HTML table inside a 2 column layout div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I really need your help and I am extremely puzzled by this at the moment as it does not make any sense to me whatsoever. I have a 2 column, centered DIV layout. What I would like to do is to get the HTML table into the right column. It seems that all my HTML coding stacks up but somewhere I guess a change needs to be made to the CSS in order to make this happen. See the example below:

[image]

Here is the CSS and HTML in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: rgb(187,195,203);
}
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
#layout {
    width: 900px;
    height: 632px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(112,112,112);
}
#box1 {
    background: rgb(141,155,169);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#box2 {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    padding: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#box3 {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
}
#box4 {
    background: #FFF;
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    height: 375px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
}
#box5 {
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    height: 375px;
}
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
}
#rightcolumn {
    border: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="layout" class="Absolute-Center">

    <div id="box1">Application Title</div>
    <div id="box2">
        <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
        <div id="rightcolumn">Some text in here later</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="box3">

        <!-- LEFT WINDOW PANE -->
        <div id="box4">

                <ul>
                    <li data-show="#1">File Information</li>
                    <li data-show="#2">Comments</li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- RIGHT WINDOW PANE -->
        <div id="box5">

            <!-- CONTENT [TAB1] -->                 
            <div style="width: 100%;">

                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>      
                        <th>Points</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>        
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>        
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Adam</td>
                        <td>Johnson</td>        
                        <td>67</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>      
                        <td>50</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table> 
                </div>  
        </div><!-- End of Box5 -->

    </div><!-- End of Box3 -->


</div><!-- End of Layout -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: rgb(187,195,203);
}
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
#layout {
    width: 900px;
    height: 632px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(112,112,112);
}
#box1 {
    background: rgb(141,155,169);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#box2 {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    padding: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#box3 {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
}
#box4 {
    background: #FFF;
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    height: 375px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
}
#box5 {
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    height: 375px;
}
#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
}
#rightcolumn {
    border: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="layout" class="Absolute-Center">

    <div id="box1">Application Title</div>
    <div id="box2">
        <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
        <div id="rightcolumn">Some text in here later</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="box3">

        <!-- LEFT WINDOW PANE -->
        <div id="box4">

                <ul>
                    <li data-show="#1">File Information</li>
                    <li data-show="#2">Comments</li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- RIGHT WINDOW PANE -->
        <div id="box5">

            <!-- CONTENT [TAB1] -->                 
            <div style="width: 100%;">

                <table style="width:100%,  clear: both">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>      
                        <th>Points</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>        
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>        
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Adam</td>
                        <td>Johnson</td>        
                        <td>67</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>      
                        <td>50</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table> 
                </div>  
        </div><!-- End of Box5 -->

    </div><!-- End of Box3 -->


</div><!-- End of Layout -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've added "clear: both" to the table with letters so it should work as you wish

Comment: Much appreciated. The reason why I chose this answer was because of the need for the 100% width for a fluid layout. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help you

Comment: @JasonKelly the layout will not be fluid though, because you are specifying a static width on the `#layout` container.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying a width for `#box5` so it's taking up 100% of the layout container. Just add a width and `float:right;` to `#box5` and it will work:

```
#box5 {
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    height: 375px;
    width:724px;
    float:right;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltj8rLsb/)